# Crystal Reports isn't display on Reporting using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I use VS2015 for my project and I want to display report using SAP Crystal Reports, I already installed this http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824. What's wrong or needed to update to display Crystal report.rpt in reporting. Thanks to all answers.

[image]

Comment: Which particular version did you install? SP?

Answer (score 0):

1. create new winform or wpf project
2. right click on the toolbox items, from context menu select choose items
3. in .NET components list, check CrystalReportViewer, click OK
4. now you have Crystal report viewer in your toolbox
5. insert that component to Winform or WPF